# Issue with replace

Tags: c#

I am new to c# programming, I have a quiz application where I use a service call to display the question and answers for the loged in user.

There are some question and answers option where I get the service response which sometimes contains "\n" (note this is **not** a newline character).

So before displaying the questions or answers I written a method to replace

> \n

with

> ""

```
static string SanitizeJSON(JSONObject input)
{   
    return input.ToString()
                .Replace(@"\", "")
                .Replace("\"", "")
                .Replace("\r", "")
                .Replace("\n", "");
}
```

And I use this when I retrieve the answers from the service response:

```
for (int i = 0; i < answers.Count; i++)
{   
    q.answers.Add(SanitizeJSON(answers.list[i].GetField("text")));
    //System.Console.Write("ANSWERSSS",SanitizeJSON(answers.list[i].GetField("text")));
    if (answers.list[i].GetField("correct").ToString() == "true") q.correctIndex = i;
}
```

But I still get the \n in the ui in spite of the above:

> {text:Answer is \n}.

Can you please let me know if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Perhaps update your question to show the UI with the value in it that you don't want.

Comment: \n and \r are whitespace characters (line feed and carriage return). I don't see how the second code snippet (working with a list of answers) is related to the first one (returning a string) - in parsed JSON, whitespace from the original should no longer appear except in literals.

Comment: the response from the service is json,like {text:Answer is \n}.I just need Answer is

Comment: @BoredomOverload's original answer was correct.

Comment: @Smith,  try this => `input.ToString().Replace("\\n", "")`

Comment: @Smith, try this also => `string replacement = Regex.Replace(input.ToString(), @"\t|\n|\r", "");`

Comment: @Smith, glad to see,  vote up also if possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sanitize your json with `Regex.Replace` method.

You can replace `\n` or `\t` or `\r` in your json with empty string (`""`).

Here i created console app for demonstration purpose.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"{'Question': 'How \n can we serve \t you better? \n\n\t\t\n\t',
                         'Answer': 'You should \n provide your \r best \n\n\r\r\t\n' }";

        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

        var sanitizedJson = SanitizeJSON(jObject);

        JObject result = JObject.Parse(sanitizedJson);

        Console.WriteLine(result);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string SanitizeJSON(JObject input)
    {
        string replacement = Regex.Replace(input.ToString(), @"\\t|\\n|\\r", string.Empty);
        return replacement.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]